# How to limit the number of markers when using React-Leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to use React-Leaflet in order to display markers only around a location given in a search bar. Naturally, whenever the map loads, every marker that is in my database is displayed on the whole map, and not just the ones close to a given location.

I did try to use bounds and boundsOptions, thinking that it could solve my problem, but I only got an error saying that there was "too much recursion".

Here is the code I am using :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import MapsAPI from "../services/mapsAPI";
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import MyContext from '../contexts/PositionContext';


const Maps = (props) => {
    
    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);

    const { position, setPosition } = useContext(MyContext);

    const fetchCoords = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await MapsAPI.findMarkers();

            setCoordinates(data);
        } 
        catch (error) {
            toast.error("Impossible de charger les données");
        }
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        fetchCoords();
    }, []);

    return ( 
        <>   
            <Map center={position} id="mapid" zoom={12} bounds={position} boundsOptions={{padding: [50, 50]}}>
                <TileLayer 
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                    maxZoom= "18"
                />
                {coordinates.map(maps => {
                    
                    const id = maps.id;
                    const ensemble = [maps.latitude, maps.longitude];
                    const adresse = maps.address;
                    return (
                        <Marker position={ensemble} key={id}>
                            <Popup>
                                {adresse}
                            </Popup>
                        </Marker>
                    )
                })
                }
            </Map>           
        </>
     );
}
 
export default Maps;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you perform a geometry check to see if the marker falls within the current map bounds and conditionally render them.

1. So you would have to make a map ref so you have access to the map component.
2. Get the map bounds like map.getBounds();
3. Use a package like https://turfjs.org/ to convert your lat/long, and map bounds into features as i don't think you can perform this check just with the map component
4. Ensure markers are within bounds by using https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanContains and render them if true